# How to Use BindingConvertible in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

When Core Data creates an `NSManagedObject Subclass` it converts String attributes into something like `@NSManaged public var name: String?` (edited)

But when trying to use `name` in a SwiftUI TextField you run into a problem:

```
@Binding var entry: Entry
TextField($entry.name)
```

Won't build, with the following error:

> 'Binding< String?>' is not convertible to 'Binding< String>'

So I tried to use `BindingConvertible` to fix the error:

```
extension Optional: BindingConvertible where Wrapped == String {
    public var binding: Binding<String> {
        let boundVal = Binding(getValue: , setValue: )
        return boundVal
}
```

But I'm not sure what to put in the `getValue: , setValue:` part of the initializer and was unable to find any answer in the docs or elsewhere.

Ideally if the unwrapped String were nil the Binding would receive an empty string otherwise it would receive the value. For setting, if the field's value is an empty String, `name` should remain nil, otherwise it's unwrapped value should be the contents of the TextField. Any idea as to how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said “it converts `String` attributes into something like `@NSManaged public var name: String`”, but based on the error, it converts to `@NSManaged public var name: String?`.

If you don't want to turn off the “Optional” setting for `name` in your data model, then you can add a non-optional accessor to `Entry` like this:

```
extension Entry {
    var nameNonOptional: String {
        get { name ?? "" }
        set { name = newValue.isEmpty ? nil : newValue }
    }
}
```

and then you can bind to the new accessor:

```
TextField($entry.nameNonOptional)
```